# Maximum number of simultaneous threads in a Winforms application

Tags: .net, winforms

I am working on a Winforms application (.NET 4.0), and I need to show 16 charts simultaneously, in 16 different threads to have a responsive UI. I am planning to use the System.Threading.Thread class directly.

Each chart requires at least 5 data-intensive SQL queries (that will be optimized in the future, but not now).

Considering all this -should I be concerned about the number of simultaneous threads? Should I implement a limit? Many thanks.

Comment: The UI is mono-threaded.

Comment: If you're talking numbers like 16, then you don't need to worry about this. However, you might look at Tasks and Timers before working with threads directly.

Comment: @JonB It is not the exact duplicate: the OP want the UI more reactive. Maybe changing the title would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI has it's own thread. **This mean you can't have different thread updating the UI** ( and note the same apply even to a WPF gui). You can better use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to call the DB in a background thread, and update the UI when finished. This is the preferred architecture.

Your application will behave as a browser which load the page then gracefully load asynchronously all the images, and you will see your chart appear dinamically, this usually make the user feel the application faster.

Having 16 Background worker just hanging from a response from a DB, even if not the best, is perfectly acceptable. using the background worker has the benefit  the thread marshalling is done automatically, just put the chart binding logic in the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handler, and the data retrieving logic in the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event handler.

Here below a snippet:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.DoWork += (sender, e) => { //data retrieving logic here }
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted+= (sender, e) => { //bind results to chart here if no canceled nor errors }
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();//starts async execution
```

By doing this way, you'll implement an asynchronous UI pattern, that is really a *must* for any reactive application.

**Addition**
Just for the sake of completeness, since the "hanging agent" is the database, you can even consider [Asynchronous ADO.NET calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This is perhaps the best you can do in term of resource usage, since this will use under the hood the  [I/O Completion Port mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to minimize the number of thread and context switches, but maybe it is a little overdesigned in your scenario. You can read further information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379553%28VS.80%29.aspx) about ado.net and I/O completion port, look at the paragraph "*True Asynchronous I/O*".